# Microsoft Teams REST API - Shifts edit comments

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to extract the comments left by users when sending time off requests on the Shifts interface through the Microsoft Graph API. I cannot seem to find in the documentation where to find this (pointed with a red arrow).

I've tried with `/schedule/shifts` endpoint but still no luck.

[image]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any API available to extract the comments left by users when sending time off requests on the Shifts.

Comment: To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT As you suggested, I have opened a feedback ticket in the portal.